# Declaration of array size is illegal

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner in Java and I can't find info on this very basic issue:

Eclipse doesn't let me declare an array of fixed size:

```
public class Camera {
    public Boolean [10] glCapabilities;
    //...
}
```

It says,

> Syntax error on token "10", delete this token

So I can declare a "dynamic" sized array but not a fixed sized one. For me it's like declaring 10 public booleans as attributes of the class.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Google is a wonderful tool. Type "Java tutorial <topic>", and you'll generally have a link to the official tutorial about <topic> as the first result.

Comment: As I was saying: I've already read on Google and on StackOverflow sooo many array examples but I couldn't find specified the fact that I can't declare the size at declaration. For me, coming from C++ it was a non-sense. After reading like 4 times the link from DreamBig, I realized. I still think that syntax I wrote should be allowed.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? I think it's clear; I've already spent 15 min on Goole before asking; about the usefulness, I didn't think I first have to make sure my question is useful to others before it's useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A declaration of an array in Java doesn't require or allow a size specification. This would require to consider `int[10]` a type, so that, for example, `type(int[10]) != type(int[5])`. But in Java you can just declare a `T[]` type without being able to force the size for the declaration.

You just create an array of the specified size during initialization:

```
boolean[] glCapabilities = new boolean[10];
```

Specifying the size during the declaration makes sense in a language which requires to know the exact size (like C/C++ in which you can allocate them on stack), but this is not required in Java, since they reside on heap in any case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. Indeed, I come from C++ and I'm sorry to say this but the differences between Java and C++ are so in C++ favor. It's the third time I'm confronting with Java lack of code to put me in charge (the other cases: operator overloading, importing mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Boolean[] glCapabilities = new Boolean[10];
```